# Segfault on closing python application

Tags: python, python-2.7, gdb, segmentation-fault

When i close my application, i am getting segmentation fault.

```
[1]+  Segmentation fault      (core dumped)
```

I ran the application through gdb and got following backtrace.

```
gdb -ex r --args python my_app

Reading symbols from /usr/bin/python2.7...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Starting program: /usr/bin/python2.7 my_app
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]   
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7fffe37e1700 (LWP 63735)]
[New Thread 0x7fffe2fe0700 (LWP 63736)]
[Thread 0x7fffe37e1700 (LWP 63735) exited]
[Thread 0x7fffe2fe0700 (LWP 63736) exited]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000d00000002 in ?? ()
```

backtrace:

```
    (gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000d00000002 in ?? ()
#1  0x00007fffef153bce in PySide::SignalManager::clear() ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpyside-python2.7.so.1.2
#2  0x00007fffef160f95 in PySide::destroyQCoreApplication() ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpyside-python2.7.so.1.2
#3  0x00007fffef161981 in PySide::runCleanupFunctions() ()
   from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpyside-python2.7.so.1.2
#4  0x00007fffef4cdcc5 in ?? ()
   from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PySide/QtCore.so
#5  0x000000000052f936 in ext_do_call (nk=<optimized out>, 
    na=<optimized out>, flags=<optimized out>, 
    pp_stack=0x7fffffffdb90, 
    func=<built-in function __moduleShutdown>)
    at ../Python/ceval.c:4330
#6  PyEval_EvalFrameEx (
    f=f@entry=Frame 0x1c6d3e0, for file /usr/lib/python2.7/atexit.py, line 24, in _run_exitfuncs (exc_info=None, func=<built-in function __moduleShutdown>, targs=(), kargs={}), 
    throwflag=throwflag@entry=0) at ../Python/ceval.c:2705
#7  0x000000000056d0aa in PyEval_EvalCodeEx (
    closure=<optimized out>, defcount=<optimized out>, 
    defs=0x0, kwcount=<optimized out>, kws=<optimized out>, 
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---return
    argcount=29807584, args=<optimized out>, locals=0x0, 
    globals=<optimized out>, co=<optimized out>)
    at ../Python/ceval.c:3252
#8  function_call (func=<optimized out>, arg=<optimized out>, 
    kw=<optimized out>) at ../Objects/funcobject.c:526
#9  0x00000000004da29f in PyObject_Call (kw=<optimized out>, 
    arg=(), func=<function at remote 0x7ffff20f59b0>)
    at ../Objects/abstract.c:2529
#10 PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords (
    func=<function at remote 0x7ffff20f59b0>, arg=(), 
    kw=<optimized out>) at ../Python/ceval.c:3889
#11 0x000000000042fa19 in call_sys_exitfunc ()
    at ../Python/pythonrun.c:1750
#12 Py_Finalize () at ../Python/pythonrun.c:424
#13 0x000000000042fb7c in Py_Exit (sts=sts@entry=0)
    at ../Python/pythonrun.c:1777
#14 0x000000000042fcb9 in handle_system_exit ()
    at ../Python/pythonrun.c:1151
#15 0x000000000042ec32 in PyErr_PrintEx (set_sys_last_vars=1)
    at ../Python/pythonrun.c:1161
#16 0x000000000042f042 in RunModule.48482 (
    module=module@entry=0x5cf692 "__main__", 
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---info sharedlibrary
    set_argv0=set_argv0@entry=0) at ../Modules/main.c:194
#17 0x000000000046aa09 in RunMainFromImporter (
    filename=0x7fffffffe35f "dcpp") at ../Modules/main.c:223
#18 Py_Main (argc=<optimized out>, argv=0x7fffffffdfd8)
    at ../Modules/main.c:601
#19 0x00007ffff7817ec5 in __libc_start_main (main=
    0x46ac3f <main>, argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffdfd8, 
    init=<optimized out>, fini=<optimized out>, 
    rtld_fini=<optimized out>, stack_end=0x7fffffffdfc8)
    at libc-start.c:287
#20 0x000000000057497e in _start ()


(gdb) info sharedlibrary
From                To                  Syms Read   Shared Object Library
0x00007ffff7ddaae0  0x00007ffff7df54e0  Yes         /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
0x00007ffff7bc19f0  0x00007ffff7bce391  Yes         /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
0x00007ffff78154a0  0x00007ffff795b413  Yes         /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
0x00007ffff75f2ed0  0x00007ffff75f39ce  Yes         /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2
0x00007ffff73eff10  0x00007ffff73f0804  Yes         /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libutil.so.1
0x00007ffff71d7e00  0x00007ffff71e7bf8  Yes (*)     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1
0x00007ffff6ed5610  0x00007ffff6f441b6  Yes         /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6
0x00007ffff6396a60  0x00007ffff63a4bcc  Yes         /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/datetime.x86_64-linux-gnu.so
0x00007ffff605f6c0  0x00007ffff6142cd8  Yes (*)     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so
0x00007ffff5deb770  0x00007ffff5e1d9dc  Yes (*)     /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/umath.so

(gdb) py-bt
#6 Frame 0x7fffe86d3620, for file /usr/lib/python2.7/atexit.py, line 24, in _run_exitfuncs (exc_info=None, func=<built-in function __moduleShutdown>, targs=(), kargs={})
    func(*targs, **kargs)
```

What's error here and how to correct it ?

Is this a [bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue1856) of python 2.7 ?

Comment: You should install debug symbols for python, QtCore.so and other *.so you are using to get more meaningful backtrace.

Comment: You're using PySide, and given it's async nature it is a quite common mistake not to properly delete resources that are still being used when Python's garbage collector begins to delete them. PySide accesses those resources at some moment, and since they are garbage collected, a segfault happens. Show us your code and we can pinpoint what resources should be deleted before closing the application.

Comment: @andrean I can't show my code, it will be great if u can guide me on debugging this

Comment: have a look at a tutorial I wrote on the subject: https://github.com/integricho/path-of-a-pyqter/tree/master/qttut08 , I had similar problems at the time like you

Comment: @andrean i have updated post, pls check whether from this u can figure out problem